# How does scope work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot figure this out as someone who has primarily worked in C.

How is the following code plausible?

```
if true
    hi = "hello"
end

puts hi
```

I'm used to `hi` not being in the scope of the `puts`, so it would error. How does scope in Ruby work. I can't seem to find a clear tutorial explaining it.

And even though that's valid, is it good practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ruby, there are 5 scopes:

- script scope
- module scope
- class scope
- method scope
- block scope

Block scopes nest, the other ones don't. Blocks can close over their lexical environment, the other ones can't. (IOW: not only do they nest inside their lexically surrounding environment, i.e. can access variables from their lexically surrounding environment, they can even continue to do so after that surrounding environment ceases to exist.)

Unlike some other languages, Ruby doesn't have a top-level or global scope for local variables. The "biggest" scope is script scope, but that isn't global, it is confined to a single script. (Usually, a script is the same as a file, but there are Ruby implementations that don't use files, so a term like "file scope" would be misleading.)

Local variables are defined from the point on where their definition is *parsed*, and initialized from the point on that their definition is *executed*. In between, when they are defined but not initialized, they evaluate to `nil`.

Consider this slightly modified example:

```
if false
  hi = 'hello'
end

hi
# => nil
# hi is defined here, because its definition was parsed

if true
  hi = 'olleh'
end

hi
# => 'olleh'
# hi is initialized here, because its definition was executed
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby we have 4 scopes -

1. top level scope
2. `def` creates a new scope
3. `class` creates a new scope
4. `module` creates a new scope.

In your case `hi` is a local variable which has been created in the *top level scope*. As I said above `if` doesn't create a new scope, so it is using the default scope, which is *top level scope*, and `hi` is created in the *top level scope*.

Example :

```
foo = 12

def baz
  p foo # undefined local variable or method `foo' 
  bar = 2 
end

bar # undefined local variable or method `bar'
```

As `def` creates a completely brand new scope, thus inside `baz`, that scope has no idea about `foo` and it objects. Similarly, inside the `baz`, I have created a new variable `bar`, but it is not known to the out side the scope of `baz`, thus top level also objects against `bar`.

Comment: blocks create a new scope as well

Comment: So is top level scope available all through the `def`? If I create a variable anywhere, even in a deeply nested if tree with for loops it's available outside of it?

Comment: @user212541 No `def` creates a new scope, which is a brand new and different from top level. For your second question, Yes.